# IE 7 opens .zip files as XML documents

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer, zip, xml

When I try clicking on a zip file link on a web page, IE 7 tries to open it as an XML document and displays:

> The XML page cannot be displayed
>   Cannot view XML input using XSL style
>   sheet. Please correct the error and
>   then click the Refresh button, or try
>   again.

I get around this by right-clicking and using *Save Target As...*  Double clicking on a .zip in the file system opens my zip program without problems.

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I found that the registry key of

```
HKU_CLASSES_ROOT\.zip
```

key had a Content Type of "text\xml".  I changed it to "application/x-zip-compressed" and IE now downloads zip files correctly.  I have XMLSpy 2010 installed and my theory is that the installation of XMLSpy caused this problem.

To fix it, run regedit.exe and navigate to the key listed above and change the Content Type to "application/x-zip-compressed" (remove the quotes).

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, and this seems to have fixed it for me with Internet Explorer 8, but not Chrome or Safari. Maybe those other browsers are using different heuristics for determining the file type.

Answer (score 1):

Does this happen with every website? Or just a specific website?
If so, could you give the link to that specific website?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the file association:

- Open **My Computer**
- On the Tools menu, click **Folder Options**
- Click the File Types tab.
- In the **Registered file types** list, click the **zip** file type
- In the **Details for ZIP Extension** section, click **change** to change what program it opens with, and set it to your zip program
- Click OK.